# MVC model in Java web application

Tags: java, model-view-controller

In the given package which class in controller, which one is View and which one is Controller. I am bit confused to corelate theory

[image]

Comment: There's no way to answer this without seeing the actual code. Files can be named anything and doesn't reflect their behavior in any way

Answer (score 0):

Based on the names of the packages, net.usermanagement.web seems to be your controller layer (`UserServlet` is a controller, it should extend `HttpServlet`) and your view layer is the webapp package. But without seeing the code inside the classes, it is impossible to tell.

Comment: Thank you, I got the clarity

Answer (score 0):

You might have already known but I still want to repeat that MVC is a software design pattern. It is just a good practice how developers organized their codes.

In your code:

- `UserDAO.java` and `User.java` act as your model layer. --  Read/write the data
- `UserServlet.java` acts as your controller layer. -- Make changes to the data before storing/displaying it.
- `user-list.jsp` and `user-form.jsp`
  acts as your view layer. -- Display the data.

Comment: Thank you so much, that is what I wanted to confirm!